# Iphone 12 battery

Tags: iphone

I bought my new iphone 12 from Apple store yesterday and the sales person told me that the battery was charged from the factory and it was ready to use. However when I got home and tried to turn on the phone, I found that the battery was zero charged. Why my new iphone wasn't charged like other mentioned that A new iPhone comes with around 50% charge on its battery before first use? Is there anything need for concern?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t worry. The battery was surely charged, but somehow it got turned on and drained. The device shuts itself down to protect the battery for months, so I would let it charge for an hour and then set it up.

After 2 hours, it should be well past 80% charged and if you notice anything, open a case with AppleCare so they have a receipt and record if it being flat when you opened the box. An unlikely event would be you seek service later, better to have this documented within a week of purchase “officially”.

This usually is a total non-event, though.